# ansible playbook to set docker env for inventory file: error passing in dict defined in inventory.yml

Tags: python, ansible

In my yaml inventory file, I have this snippet:

```
 docker_env: {
        "SHOPIFY_PAYMENTS": 1,
        "SHOPIFY_PROMISE_DATES": 1
      }
```

which defines a dict.

and in my playbook, I have this:

```
 name: Start django container
  docker_container:
    image: "{{ image_name }}"
    labels: "{{ django_container_labels }}"
...
    env: "{{ docker_env }}"
```

However, I get this error:

```
TASK [Start django container] 
fatal: [...growthpath.com.au]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Non-string value found for env option. Ambiguous env options must be wrapped in quotes to avoid them being interpreted. Key: SHOPIFY_PAYMENTS"}
```

Documentation for env says: "
Dictionary of key,value pairs."

"labels" works; it has the same documentation.  This variable is defined in variables.yml, an included file, as:

```
django_container_labels: {
traefik.http.routers.django-api-router.entrypoints: "web_http,web_https",
....
```

in other words, I can't see any real difference between docker_env and django_container_labels, except one works and one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

ok. THe fix is to do this, quote the value. The error message was more precise than I expected.

```
 docker_env: {
        "SHOPIFY_PAYMENTS": "1",
        "SHOPIFY_PROMISE_DATES": "1"
      }
```